# im trying to change the value of a text inside an if statement but it doesnt work i think i use wrong logic

Tags: javascript, html

So i have made this code that when i click the check button it changes the text of message every time , depending on the number input in guess variable .

Though my logic to declare the variables in the beggining and then use them seems okey to me, it doesnt work
Can someone explain why my logic is wrong?

```
// for example i declared 
let message = document.querySelector('.message').textContent;

//and then i used message inside if to change the text
message = '‼ Type a Number';
```

why is this wrong?

```
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function () {
      let score = 20;
      const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
      let message = document.querySelector('.message').textContent;
      if (!guess) {
        message = '‼ Type a Number';
      } else if (secretNumber === guess) {
        message = 'You Won ';
      } else if (secretNumber < guess) {
        message = 'It is a lower Number!';
        score += -1;
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
      } else if (secretNumber > guess) {
        message = 'It is a higher Number!';
        score += -1;
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
      }
    });
```

Comment: by the way ... `score += -1;` === `score -= 1;` not your issue though

Comment: you do `let message = document.querySelector('.message').textContent;` ... but then you never assign `message` back to the `document.querySelector('.message').textContent` - so it'll never change

Comment: @bravo thank you for your answer . Should i try document.querySelector('.message').textContent = message and then message = '‼ Type a Number'

Comment: why would you do it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems (or the two that jump out at me) are that you redefine `score` every time the function is run. That is, every time you click the button, `score` is reset to 20 and can only take on values of `20` or `19` depending on the user's input. The other problem is you never re-assign the `textContent` of the `.message` element.

To resolve this, just move that declaration of `score` outside of the function and add an extra message reassignment line like so:

```
let score = 20;
document.querySelector(".check").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // the 'let score' line has been removed from in here
    const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
    let message = document.querySelector('.message').textContent;
    // Rest of your code ...
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = message;
});
```

Also note (as [Bravo pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542484/im-trying-to-change-the-value-of-a-text-inside-an-if-statement-but-it-doesnt-wor/72542621#comment128145238_72542484)) that your use of `+=` and `-` overlaps - you should just use the compound assignment operator with subtraction (i.e., `score -= 1` not `score += -1`. This also works for other operators, such as multiplication `*=` and division `/=`.)

Comment: thats seems to be the solution , thank you! But why i have to reassigned at the end ?